# NextJS fails with UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH after redirect from server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is my first NextJs application and I am using the serverActions experimental feature to manage form submissions and handle that via server side.

Here is my code:

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { authService } from "@/services";

async function logoutUser() {
  "use server"
  
  authService.logout();
  cookies().delete('currentUser');
  redirect('/');
}

export default () => {
  return <>
    <form action={logoutUser} className="flex flex-col gap-3">
      <button className="btn btn-primary normal-case w-full" type="submit">Logout</button>
    </form>
  </>
}
```

The idea here is that I want to redirect back to home page after the user logs out.

However, whenever the code executes, I get the following error:

```
failed to get redirect response TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11) {
  cause: RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header
      at write (/Users/robison/Documents/Development/prototypes/watchlist-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:67105)
      at _resume (/Users/robison/Documents/Development/prototypes/watchlist-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:66726)
      at resume (/Users/robison/Documents/Development/prototypes/watchlist-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:65413)
      at connect (/Users/robison/Documents/Development/prototypes/watchlist-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:65301) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH'
  }
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of nextjs are you using?

Comment: I was using Next13, but I gave up and decided to use Svelte instead

Comment: Anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

To anyone who might be getting this error in Next.js 13 or 14...check that the URL you're querying is correct and not redirecting. I was making POST requests to my API base URL without "www" and the requests were forwarding to the www address (and the POST request then fails due to a 301 Permanent Redirect), but rather than getting that message specifically in an error it's just a generic "cause: RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header." That being said it might also be the opposite error, in which your base URL without www forwards to your www address

Comment: Adding www just gave me an HSTS error. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the authService.logout() code I'm going to assume there is a DELETE request that occurs here.

See [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/53843). There was a regression introduced in NEXTJS.

I was experiencing a similar issue. Upgrading to the latest version of NEXT helped resolve it for me. Version 13.4.19 as of this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to resolve this by switching from fetch to axios.

For those who might not have heard of axios - it's a drop-in replacement for `fetch`. NextJS App router wraps `fetch`, and UNDICI is what fetch is NextJS calls fetch (which is in your error message), so to help isolate the issue, I switched to a different HTTP client and it worked. Doesn't have to be axios btw, many http clients exists:

1. Axios
2. Got
3. SuperAgent

Many more.

For a full solution, see here: https://janac.medium.com/nextjs-fails-with-und-err-req-content-length-mismatch-after-redirect-from-server-0acdc0bfb194

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to resolve this by switching from fetch to axios.

For those who might not have heard of axios - it's a simple drop-in replacement for `fetch`. NextJS App router wraps `fetch`. There is an open issue related to fetch  so to help isolate the issue, I switched to a different HTTP client and it worked. Many alternatives exist including:

1. Axios
2. Got
3. SuperAgent

And more.

For a full solution see here: https://janac.medium.com/nextjs-fails-with-und-err-req-content-length-mismatch-after-redirect-from-server-0acdc0bfb194

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [startTransition](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions#custom-invocation-using-starttransition) and call `logoutUser` from inside it. If that doesn't work, you can try [this article](https://medium.com/@kaloyan_17221/fix-vercel-next-js-fetch-failed-from-undici-polyfill-8c66346c9c2f) that discusses about a few fixes regarding this exact problem, which clearly looks like an error related to `undici` module looking at your error logs.

Comment: startTransition only works for client components though, and I don't think you can blame undici for this, the body length *should* match that header